# REGEX where I can remove bits in the string and still get constant groupings?

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-group

I have a string which looks like this:

`C1 V1 C2 V2 C3 V3 C4 V4.zip`

where C1, C2 etc are Constants which I can use other REGEX's to identify, and V1, V2 etc are variables which can literally be anything. At the moment I have a regex which puts the full string in nice groups for me - for example 'C1' is in group 1, 'V1' is in group 2 etc etc -

```
(C1)(.*?)(C2)(.*?)(C3)(.*?)C4(.*?)(.zip)
```

but I was wondering if there was a way to keep these groups/matches if I was to remove a portion of the string, like:

`C1 V1 C2 V2 C4 V4.zip1` < I skipped the 3's here.

https://regex101.com/r/lpiG4H/6

If this is not possible just let me know :)

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "keep these groups/matches"?

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/pyIcqM/1 ?

Comment: Perhaps `(?:(C\d )|(V\d ?(?:\.zip)?))` ? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/pyIcqM/2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep group 1 and group 2 and capture `.zip` in group 3 you could try using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

That would match:

[`(C\d)(.*?(?=C\d|\.zip))|(\.zip$)`](https://regex101.com/r/M4Vfya/1)

- `(C\d)` Match C followed by a digit in a capturing group
- `(` Capturing group

  - `.*?` Match any character zero or more times non greedy
  - `(?=C\d|\.zip)` Positive lookahead that assert that what follows is either C followed by a digit or .zip at the end of the string `$`
- `)`
- `|` Or
- `(\.zip$)` Capture in a group `.zip` and assert the end of the line

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex, which makes each group of constants and variables optional

```
((C1)(.*?))?((C2)(.*?))?((C3)(.*?))?((C4)(.*?))?(.zip)
```

[Tested here.](https://regex101.com/r/1YsV7w/1)